# Update database monthly ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a table "Point" with an integer column "monthly_point", and a table "User" with an integer column "Give_Point". I want to update the value of "Give_Point" is value of "monthly_point" every month. How can i do that? Thanks all.

Comment: Take a look - https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 0):

There is a gem for such tasks, called [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq)

It uses sidekiq for background jobs.

Here is an example

```
class MonthlyPointWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence { monthly }

  def perform
    # do your work here
  end
end
```

[Whenever](http://%20github.com/javan/whenever) just puts your tasks into the crontab and executes it using cron.

It's up to you which one you will use for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cron-jobs` to achieve this so, use the `whenever gem`
Just add `gem 'whenever', require: false` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.
Then within your application’s root directory, run the following command:

```
`bundle exec wheneverize`
```

This will add a schedule file to your config folder `(config/schedule.rb)`. This file is where you set up your scheduled tasks. You can use regular cron scheduling, or you can use a more idiomatic DSL for scheduling. The following examples are take from the gem’s README.md:

```
every 3.hours do
  runner "MyModel.some_process"
  rake "my:rake:task"
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end

every 1.day, :at => '4:30 am' do
  runner "MyModel.task_to_run_at_four_thirty_in_the_morning"
end

every :hour do # Many shortcuts available: :hour, :day, :month, :year, :reboot
  runner "SomeModel.ladeeda"
end

every :sunday, :at => '12pm' do # Use any day of the week or :weekend, :weekday
  runner "Task.do_something_great"
end

every '0 0 27-31 * *' do
  command "echo 'you can use raw cron syntax too'"
end`
```

Once you’ve set up your scheduled tasks in `config/schedule.rb`, you still need to apply them to your crontab. From your terminal, use the whenever command to update your crontab:

## Change to your application's directory.

`cd /my/app`

## View config/schedule.rb converted to cron syntax

`bundle exec whenever`

[Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)